# Runtime error in my app

Tags: android, junit

I am building an app. When I run it, it gives me this error:

> junit:junit:q.12

I searched it on Google, but I could not find any match or something related. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file, change `junit:junit:q.12` to this:

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked :)